# Laravel 4.2 getting error array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

I am having a trouble with my project, It shows the error `array_merge(): Argument #2` i have tried using `composer update` but the update do not work because it shows the same error in the console, i don't know what cause the problem, i have not touched it and anyone else should be working on it, so if any help would be thankfull.

im using laravel 4.2 this is the error stack

```
6. ErrorException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­ProviderRepository.php188
5. Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleError
<#unknown>0
4. array_merge
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­ProviderRepository.php188
3. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository loadManifest
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­ProviderRepository.php50
2. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository load
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­start.php210
1. require
…/­bootstrap/­start.php60
0. require_once
/­home/­{myproject}/­public_html/
```

The error does not come from a code i write myself, but from the core of laravel in `/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­ProviderRepository.php188` i have read that the `service.json` file maybe corrupted, i have deleted it and try to run `composer update` but the error persist and the update does not run

Comment: your second parameter to the `array_merge` is not an array

Comment: Can you show the part og the code where you've used `array_merge();`? Or what initially triggers this error (in case the is written somewhere)...

Comment: As i said i don't know what cause the error, i did not uploaded anything to the project and there is no cron job or any that upload it automatically, the error comes from `/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­ProviderRepository.php188`

Comment: I have the same error in a legacy web application with php 7.2 and laravel 4.2 on centos :(